# Three.js meshphongmaterial map not appearing

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, textures

I'm trying to take a sphere and make clouds with it in threejs (around a blue, smaller sphere). The cloud sphere isn't showing up, even though the blue sphere is showing up. There are also no errors showing up, I think it is that the object is transparent on its entire body. Thanks for helping!

```js
const cloudTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./cloud_texture_2.jpg')
const clouds = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xfffff, shininess: 0, map: cloudTexture, alphaMap : cloudTexture, transparent : true, depthWrite  : false}))
scene.add(clouds)
```

And here is the image:
[image: black and white noise texture]

Comment: Have you tried `depthTest: false`?

Comment: @Marquizzo what does that do?
I added it, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: If `true`, it'll test if the object is behind another one to determine whether it should be rendered or not. If `false`, it will not perform this test and will render it regardless. Either way, if that didn't work then I'd need to see a working example to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: The answer is that it is a CORS error -- the image is being blocked. I am changing the code to make it follow a server, and it seems to work now :). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: depthTest should be selected, and CORS errors kept the image from being fetched.
It is now fixed; I am using a local server on vscode.